# Setting Width of absolute element after child element widths

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to set the width of a nested absolute positioned ul based off of the child li elements width. Assume all elements are to float left and display block.

This for a drop down navigation so only one nested ul will show.

The nest ul element is being set at 0 for the width.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li> <span></span>
     <ul>
        <li>link</li>
        <li>link</li>
     </ul>
  </li>

  <li> 
     <ul><span>link</span>
        <li>link</li>
        <li>link</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('ul li ul').each(function() {
        var width = 0;
        $(this).children('li').each(function() {
            width += $(this).outerWidth(true);

        });
            $(this).width(width);
    });
});
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
}

ul ul {
    display: none;

}
```

Comment: so what is happening? can you crate a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j2eMz/1/

Comment: The element with is being set to 0

Comment: can you share the relevant css also..

Comment: the second ul is suppose to be horizontal as well set to the calculated value of all the elements ups

Comment: the problem is you have the inner ul hidden when the width is calculated.. so the `ul` and its children will not be present in the render tree because of that its dimensions will not be present

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j2eMz/6/

Comment: as a solution try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j2eMz/7/

Comment: could i do it with visibility hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are hiding the inner `ul` element so when you are calculating the width those elements are not displayed so it will not have any dimension.

One possible solution is to hide it using positioning like

```
ul ul {
    display: none;
}
ul ul.preload {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: -10000px;
}
```

then

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('ul li ul').each(function () {
        var width = 0;
        $(this).children('li').each(function () {
            width += $(this).outerWidth(true);

        });
        $(this).width(width);
    });
    $('ul.preload').removeClass('preload')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j2eMz/)

Comment: @Ray the fiddle seems to be working for me in FF... can you recreate the issue